# Keeping a remote disk mounted

Tags: network, sleep-wake, mount

I have a website that I maintain mounted locally on a MacBook Pro with Monterey 12.0.1, using [MacFUSE and SSHFS](https://osxfuse.github.io).  From time to time, an operation involving a directory there fails with "device not configured."  The fix is to `umount` and then mount it again, which takes a few seconds.

I think what triggers it is the laptop going to sleep, but it could be a timeout.  If a timeout, a background process accessing the mount point periodically would prevent it, but that would of course fail when the laptop sleeps.

Is there a better solution?  (Hosting provider says SMB and NFS will not work).

Comment: Have you tried Mountain Duck? https://mountainduck.io

Comment: MacFUSE and SSHFS are doing what I need except for this minor issue.  So $39 for Mountain Duck is too much.  Plus, the complaints by the copyright owner of MacFUSE suggests (without naming names) that Mountain Duck may be in copyright violation.

Comment: I totally hear your concerns. I still think that it would be a useful experiment to run the free trial of Mountain Duck to see if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way appears to be using cron to 'touch' a file in the remote directory every five minutes.  This will keep the mounted directory from becoming "unconfigured" but it won't fix it if that happens.  So I added another job to run in the wee hours each morning to umount and re-mount.